# Read co-workers planner tasks

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to retrieve a list of co-worker Planner tasks via the API?
For example the graph explorer provides the following GET endpoint:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/coworker-mail/planner/tasks

I can get results back using my own email address in url, but always a 403 failure when using a coworkers email.
I have Group.Read.All as a delegated permission on the app, I am an admin user and have granted consent via the admin consent endpoint to no avail.
Is this possible? If not what am i missing and why does the explorer/api expose that endpoint?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Querying other users' data is currently not allowed. You can provide feedback about this behavior [here](https://planner.uservoice.com).

The endpoint exists to support reading signed in user's data. "me" segment is simply an alias that in reality executes the request against /users/(signed in user id).